# Is there a LeechBlock extension (or extension with a similar functionality) for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, website, blocking

The [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476) Firefox extension lets you block specific websites after a predefined time etc. Is there a similar extension for Google Chrome?

Comment: Add superuser.com first thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji), which limits the amount of time you can spend on time wasting websites per day.

Comment: Comment by [Aliza](http://superuser.com/users/26627/aliza): Unfortunately, StayFocusd makes no distinction between work hours and non-work hours.